# PHP virtualhost's settings issue

Tags: apache, security, virtualhost

I have a functional virtualhost set us

```
Listen 1234

<VirtualHost *:1234>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/localuser/sites/testphp"
  ServerName localhost
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testphp-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/testphp-access_log" common 
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Users/localuser/sites/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

PHP page is accessible by url `localhost:1234`.

Now I need to add another project, but I want to put it to different folder instead `sites`.
So I add another virtualhost settings as

```
Listen 1235

<VirtualHost *:1235>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/localuser/Desktop/PE_RS/Projekty/php/hello-slim/public"
  ServerName localhost
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/hello-slim-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/hello-slim-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/Users/localuser/Desktop/PE_RS/Projekty/php/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But in this case I'm getting for `localhost:1235`

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I don't know if it does matter, but I have set in httpd-userdir.conf `UserDir sites`.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, settings are all right. The issue is related to the folder/file permissions. I think that it was wrong to have PHP projects folder on Desktop. After move it into ~ and fix permissions by command `sudo chmod -R 777 php` (what is essential of this solution) all works!

Inspiration came from
[askubuntu.com...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584797/virtualhost-into-separate-partition-or-drive#answers-header)